# Why does the camera not follow the object when I'm editing the animation and when I move a line?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I'm new at animating keyframes. The problem I have is that, when I move a line in keyframe to make it slower/fast, the object in that line goes outside of the camera and then comes back to the camera... I'm following a tutorial for this animation but it didn't explain this deep in keyframing.
[Here's a clip of the animation to see the problem.](https://streamable.com/k765d4)

Here are the keyframes of the camera before I shift the line. In this case the plane and the camera are at the same speed all over the animation.

[image]

Now I shift the line, and the plane goes faster than the camera for a short time and then comes back in the camera view.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 3):

Before you move the keyframes line, camera and plane are at the same speed.

By moving the line for the camera, you do so the camera position associated with these keyframes is reached later.

So for this period, the camera is slower and the plane (unchanged keyframes) is at the same speed but will be faster than the camera for this period.

But, as the next keyframe line is unchanged, the position associated to it will be reached at the same time for both plane and camera.

So for this period, the camera is faster than the plane.

After that, as next keyframes are unchanged, both are still at the same speed.

---

To say it another way:

Keyframes are defining position, rotation, etc.

Keyframes positions and intervals between keyframes will drive the speed.

Comment: sorry, i dint understand very well..